# Howcome my function to calculate the length of a string returns a negative value?

Tags: c

I've written a function using pointer arithmetic to calculate the length of a string but it only seems to work properly by using a hackish methodology.

I've tried using my understanding of memory addressing to make the function work as intended.

```
int getLength(const char *str) {
    int length;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        length += str - (++str);
    }
    return abs(length);
}

int getLength(const char *str) {
    int length;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        length += str + (++str);
    }
    return length;
}
```

The first function returns the correct length, but the second one returns 0, why is this?

Comment: What do you expect to get when you add two pointers like that? `length` is also not initialized.

Comment: Umm ... your question doesn't make sense.  Zero is not a negative value.

Comment: Both are broken as you never initialise `length`, among other reasons.

Comment: For longer strings, you will find `strlen()` much more efficient as it is optimized to compare more than one byte per-iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question is off-topic, because it lacks a [mcve], even though your problem itself is not off-topic. As a new user here, also make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Ace: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both functions are incorrect because:

- you do not initialize `length`, so the behavior is undefined.
- taking the absolute value is a lame attempt at fixing the problem... correcting the symptoms, but not addressing the problem. Don't do this, investigate the issue.
- `length += str - (++str);` has undefined behavior because the side effect on `str` may happen before or after taking the value of the left operand `str`.
- `length += str + (++str);` is a constraint violation: adding 2 pointers is not allowed in C.

You should instead write:

```c
size_t getLength(const char *str) {
    size_t length = 0;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        length++;
        str++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Depending on the target architecture, it may be more efficient to only increment `str` and compute the difference at the end:

```c
size_t getLength(const char *str) {
    const char *p = str;
    while (*p++ != '\0')
        continue;
    /* p was incremented beyond the null terminator, hence decrease the difference by 1 */
    return p - str - 1;
}
```

Comment: Almost 3 years on and now I understand, so just to clarify, you initialise length unlike I did (my length variable could have contained garbage depending on several factors given there was no assignment after the declaration), you then increment length by 1, and increment the pointer to move to the next character, this is obviously repeated until the null terminator is reached, which then ends the loop and returns the number of iterations until the null terminator was reached, giving the final length of the string. Correct?

Comment: @Ace: yes that's correct. measuring the length of a C string is simply counting the number of bytes up to and not including the null terminator.

Answer (score -3):

Your functions have a lots of issues:

1. You do not initialize the automatic variables.
2. Your pointer arithmetic does not make too much sense (at leat I cant understand what is the logic behind it)
3. result pf operations where on one size you have the lvalue and post(pre)increment or decrement is undefined (it saying quicker an Undefined Behaviour)

Below you have two almost the same versions of the strlen function. Sometimes small changes may have large impact on the function peformance depending on the target hardware.

this verison is more optimal for ARM targets

```
size_t getlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;

    while(*p++);

    return p - s - 1;
}
```

this one is better for the x86 targets

```
size_t getlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;

    while(*p)
    {
        p++;
    }

    return p - s;
}
```

Comment: any comments form the dv-ters? What is wron in my answer guys to dv me?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume the problem is that the question is "why does my code not work" and this doesn't answer that question.